# How can I limit the scope of org-babel named code blocks?

Tags: org-babel

Is it possible to limit the scope of named code blocks to subtrees for example?

For example, if I have a code block named foo, can I limit this "foo" to only be available for subheadings and not for the whole org document?

I find that if it's a big document, I need to get creative in naming things, cause there's probably another code block with that same name

Comment: No, `#+name`s are global in a buffer. If you refer to a name, babel will only ever give you the first one with that name.